# Fastest way to git merge down

Tags: git

I find myself merging latest into my feature branches several times per day.

Is there a faster way to

```
git add --all && git commit -m '' && git push (or stash)
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature/previous-branch-name
git merge main
```

Comment: `git fetch` and `git merge origin/main`?

Comment: ^ put a double ampersand (`&&`) between, in case the fetch fails for whatever reason

Comment: Brilliant @Brian61354270 ! Just merge origin directly. Thank you!

Comment: What branch are you pushing?

Comment: Just pushing or stashing my current branch's unsaved work before pulling changes in.

Comment: You could develop on local `main`, naming the feature branch only on push (or renaming locally some other time), and then you'd just need `git pull`. However, generally unnecessary to pull latest so frequently, IMO.